# Container View is not showing for nonstoryboard xib

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xib

When I am using different Xib file for Swift 2.0 I cannot find Container View in the view collections on the right bottom corner of the XCode. How can I use container view for non storyboard xib.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Container Views, Prototype cells etc (almost all the new Interface
builder things released after storyboards) are available to be used in
storyboards file only.

I believe the xib are parsed with a different parser (old one) and
there fore these features were not added as its parser was not updated.

Comment: So how can I use tab bar and switch between two views which have different view controller and layout?

Comment: xib also dont have segues. so you would have to do all the push and presentation of views programatically. i would advice using storyboard since that will make the project more upto modern standards and easy to maintain